# how to predict next month sales using this data

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, arima

this is the csv file data(daily sales predict.csv which i used below)

```
TOTAL     = c(198230142.89,129497034.78,186477295.56,118126147.20,
              140245618.01,110070803.09,70209156.29,131272373.74,144268706.02,
              21047760.22)
Monthname = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

here is the piece of code i tried so far

```
library(forecast)
#trying to predict next month sales(november)     

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  mydat<- read.csv("daily sales predict.csv")
  predictmodelling=data_frame(

    Saledate=mydat$monthname,
    total=mydat$TOTAL
  )

  tData <- ts(predictmodelling$total,
              start=c(2018,1),
              frequency=12)

  Mod1 <- auto.arima(tData)
  summary(Mod1)
  print(Mod1)
  # 2 period forecast
  plot(forecast(Mod1, h=60))

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for the question, you can play with other values of (p, d, q) for better accuracy.

```
x <- c(198230142.89,129497034.78,186477295.56,118126147.20,140245618.01,110070803.09,70209156.29,131272373.74,144268706.02,21047760.22)
df = data.frame(x)

ts_data = ts(df$x, start = c(2018,1), end = c(2018,10), frequency = 12)

plot(ts_data)

#this gives value for p

acf(ts_data)

#this gives value for q

pacf(ts_data)
# so we have p = 1, d = 1, q = 0

# differentiating the series one time only so d = 1

fit = arima(log(ts_data), c(1,1,0))

#here I am predicting for next 2 months

predicted_val = predict(fit, n.ahead = 1*2)

actual_val = 2.718^predicted_val$pred

print(actual_val)

49577035,33805119
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i am getting an error Error in df$x <- x : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @RohitJha there was a syntax error. Please try again and mark it accepted if you find helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: @RohitJha. It's working fine in my editor. can you please run this code in a fresh editor after clearing all variable and data frames stored in the current environment. Also, run code line by line. Which line of code is producing the error and what is the error?

Comment: i am getting error this one     Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6337
Warning: Error in <-: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  [No stack trace available]
Error in df$x <- x : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @RohitJha Try it again, please.

Comment: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Comment: Use log for it.   plot(log(df))

Comment: one more thing how to plot the actual value in a hist graph

Comment: this the last thing i have to do to plot in graph

Comment: no this is not working it is showing somthing in frequencies

Comment: in doing plot it is showing somthig like 2018.84,2018.90

Comment: @RohitJha I hope you will understand what I am going to tell you. It is not good practice to ask everything on the forum. Please do some research on your own so that you can learn something. I am posting a link for your further help but you have to do this on your own. [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-make-a-histogram-with-basic-r/). I wish you a luck and hope you will understand my intent. Also, accept my answer if you have found it useful in solving your problem up to certain extent. Thank you !!